# Typewriter quotation marks in texttt

Tags: punctuation, typewriter

I'd like to do the text

```
"conservative"
```

with the quotation marks into a `\texttt`. However, when I do so, the first quotation mark is removed. I'm using the [LNCS documentclass](http://www.springer.com/computer/lncs?SGWID=0-164-6-793341-0), I'm not sure if this has something to do with it. I also can't escape the first `"`, then it puts two dots above the `c`, which is wrong.

Comment: 1. Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228). `\documentclass{llncs}
\begin{document}
\texttt{"conservative"}
\end{document}` does it here. 2. `\"` is _not_ escaping.

Comment: For the record, the problem seems to have been fixed, at least with TeX Live 2016 and llncs.cls 2015/06/24 v2.20.

Answer (score 8):

this is a bit of a plain-tex hack, but it'll get you what you want.

```
\texttt{\char`\"}
```

you might want to make this into a command:

```
\newcommand*{\ditto}{\texttt{\char`\"}}
```

Answer (score 8):

A bit simpler: `\texttt{"{}conservative"{}}`

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Answer (score 0):

I finally found an answer that works for me: Use the command `\textquotedbl` for double quotes in `\texttt{}` environments.

For your example, the result would be: `\texttt{\textquotedbl conservative\textquotedbl}`