# How to get vertical quotes by default with tt fonts?

Tags: fonts

I would like to always get vertical quotes for `'` and `"` when using the tt font.  I can get that with the upquote package for verbatim environments, and with the macros provided by textcomp, but I would also like it to be the default for `\texttt` and `\ttfamily`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{textcomp, upquote}
\begin{document}
\verb|This is a vertical quote: '|

\texttt{I wish this were a vertical quote: '
(like this one: \textquotesingle)}
\end{document}
```

Is there a way to do that?  And let me add, with pdflatex, before someone suggests some remapping command that only works with xelatex/lualatex.

**Edit**:
I have succeeded in implementing a solution via Heiko Oberdiek's lm-ec-tt.map method, at least via the `\pdfmapfile` command.  (I have not yet tried to put the modified .map and .enc files in my ~/texmf area.)

But I also succeeded in getting `\ttfamily` redefined, which is a path I think I'd prefer.  Unfortunately, `\texttt` still doesn't work.  In my (obviously wrong) understanding of the code in article.cls, `\texttt` should be defined in terms of `\ttfamily`.  So why doesn't the following work for `\texttt`?:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{textcomp, upquote}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand\ttfamily
        {\not@math@alphabet\ttfamily\mathtt
         \fontfamily\ttdefault\selectfont
         \@noligs}% all I do is add this
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\texttt{texttt: quote:'; doublequote:"; grave:`}\par      % doesn't work
{\ttfamily ttfamily: quote:'; doublequote:"; grave:`}\par % works
\verb| verb: quote:'; doublequote:"; grave:`|\par
\end{document}
```

Comment: does this help:  [Non-curly quotes in code?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/238298) ?

Comment: @barbarabeeton: No, that answer uses upquote, which only affects `\verb` and verbatim.  I know about that (see my MRE).  I'm looking for a way to get `\texttt` to do the same thing.

Comment: another possibility: [Typewriter quotation marks in texttt](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/86311/579).  it only covers the double quote/ditto, but the same mechanism can be used for the single quote (although i can't think of a good short name for it).

Comment: @barbarabeeton, thanks for your persistence, but that's not what I'm asking either.  I _can get_ a vertical quote in `\texttt` with `\textquotesingle/dbl`; what I want is for the characters `'` and `"` to be _interpreted_ as vertical quotes within `\texttt`.

Comment: Why don't you just define a new environment or macro to replace `\ttfamily` or whatever? Note that you certainly can get this to work in pdfTeX  because you can always define a new font and use that for typewriter text. But you probably don't want to go to that much trouble.

Comment: @cfr, that sounds promising, but I'm missing something.  See my attempt in the edited question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## LuaTeX

If LuaTeX or XeTeX is an option, then the default font of package `fontspec` uses the Latin Modern fonts (the successors of the Computer Modern fonts).
There, the single and double quote are plain vertical:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\begin{document}
\verb|These are vertical quotes: ' and "|

\texttt{These are vertical quotes: ' and "}

\texttt{These are vertical quotes: \textquotesingle\ and \textquotedbl}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

## XeTeX

XeTeX also work, but the spacing is different, because it respects the space factor settings better that are active in `\texttt` in opposite to `\verb` that automatically sets `\frenchspacing`.

> [image: Result XeTeX]

## pdfTeX

A clean solution for pdfTeX would be to change the encoding of the typewriter font to replace the single quote. The map file entries look like:

```
ec-lmtt10 LMMono10-Regular " enclmec ReEncodeFont " <lm-ec.enc <lmtt10.pfb
```

The encoding is defined in file `lm-ec.enc`. It can be located via:

```
kpsewhich lm-ec.enc
```

This file can be copied to `lm-ec-tt.enc`, which replaces `/quotesingleright` by `/quotesingle`:

```
...
/ampersand
/quotesingle
/parenleft
...
```

Then a map file `lm-ec-tt.map` for the affected fonts can be created that uses the new encoding file `lm-ec-tt.enc`:

```
ec-lmtt10 LMMono10-Regular " enclmec ReEncodeFont " <lm-ec-tt.enc <lmtt10.pfb
ec-lmtt12 LMMono12-Regular " enclmec ReEncodeFont " <lm-ec-tt.enc <lmtt12.pfb
ec-lmtt8 LMMono8-Regular " enclmec ReEncodeFont " <lm-ec-tt.enc <lmtt8.pfb
ec-lmtt9 LMMono9-Regular " enclmec ReEncodeFont " <lm-ec-tt.enc <lmtt9.pfb
ec-lmtti10 LMMono10-Italic " enclmec ReEncodeFont " <lm-ec-tt.enc <lmtti10.pfb
ec-lmtto10 LMMonoSlant10-Regular " enclmec ReEncodeFont " <lm-ec-tt.enc <lmtto10.pfb
ec-lmvtk10 LMMonoPropLt10-Bold " enclmec ReEncodeFont " <lm-ec-tt.enc <lmvtk10.pfb
ec-lmvtko10 LMMonoPropLt10-BoldOblique " enclmec ReEncodeFont " <lm-ec-tt.enc <lmvtko10.pfb
ec-lmvtl10 LMMonoPropLt10-Regular " enclmec ReEncodeFont " <lm-ec-tt.enc <lmvtl10.pfb
ec-lmvtlo10 LMMonoPropLt10-Oblique " enclmec ReEncodeFont " <lm-ec-tt.enc <lmvtlo10.pfb
ec-lmvtt10 LMMonoProp10-Regular " enclmec ReEncodeFont " <lm-ec-tt.enc <lmvtt10.pfb
ec-lmvtto10 LMMonoProp10-Oblique " enclmec ReEncodeFont " <lm-ec-tt.enc <lmvtto10.pfb
```

Then the pdfTeX document starts at the very beginning with the replacement of these fonts:
\pdfmapfile{=lm-ec-tt.map}

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\begin{document}
\verb|These are vertical quotes: ' and "|

\texttt{These are vertical quotes: ' and "}

\texttt{These are vertical quotes: \textquotesingle\ and \textquotedbl}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result pdfTeX]

The trick via the map and encoding file works for this case, because the bounding boxes of the symbols that are exchanged are the same.

Comment: I'm using pdflatex, so I'll try to digest what you said about mapping tonight.  Is there an area in my ~/.texmf directory where I can drop a new map file and have it be used automatically?  (And would that be a bad idea for some reason?)  Also, I'm using zlmtt, not lmodern, since I'm usually using some other roman font (libertine or XCharter, usually).  I'll assume that zlmtt should still work, since it's supposed to be the latin modern tt font.

Comment: @dedded Usually, the local or home tree (`kpsewhich -expand-var '$TEXMFLOCAL'` or `kpsewhich -expand-var '$TEXMFHOME'` are the roots, where the user can add the files. Just use the same directory hierarchy as the original files. The local texmf tree also nees a run of `texhash` (or `mktexlsr`).

Comment: @dedded The method of the answer can also work for other fonts if the straight glyph versions are contained in the Type 1 font. The map entries needs to be identified (`pdftex.map`). If an encoding file is given, then it needs to be modified, see the answer. The glyph positions and names can be reviewed by a font editor, e.g. `fontforge`.

Comment: I got this to work (so far just with \pdfmapfile), thank you very much.  You mentioned needing to run `texhash` or `mktexlsr` if I were to put these files in my texmf tree.  In this link (https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/255709/), @cfr recommends against running `updmap`.  Will there be similar issues with  `texhash` or `mktexlsr`?  Following a different path, I also succeeded in redefining `\ttfamily` without making a new .map file.  If I can only get `\texttt` working, that technique is promising.  See the original question that I just edited.

Comment: @dedded `texhash`/`mktexlsr` is not the same as `updmap`. The former commands just updates the `ls-R` file at the root of the `texmf` tree. Usually the TeX programs (more precise, programs that use the `kpathsea` library) do a fast lookup via `ls-R` for the system and local `texmf` trees to find a file and they do not search the file system tree (slow operation).

Comment: So I wouldn't need to remember to re-run `texhash` when I update texlive?

Comment: @dedded "update texlive" can be anything. If files are added/deleted from a `texmf`tree, then `ls-R`should be regenerated. I assume `tlmgr` does this automatically. But if files are added/deleted manually, then `texhash` needs to be run for the tree.

Comment: I find that I cannot use this answer, because in the end it's not really practical to customize the Latex environment at work; and there's no sense in customizing a personal environment in this way when some documents are developed collaboratively.  But I feel like I have learned a great deal from it and that I have a better handle on how at least some aspects of fonts work in Latex than I ever had.